# Why I get different result when I use (select * vs select uuid) which followed by order by at the end?

Tags: mysql

I have two select statement in MySQL.  First:

```
select o.uuid
from wmsStockInBill o
where 1=1 and o.orguuid = '4028c08d555dfd9901555e1287f50002'
order by o.inDate desc`
```

I get the following result

[image: uuids]

Second:

```
select *
from wmsStockInBill o
where 1=1 and o.orguuid = '4028c08d555dfd9901555e1287f50002'
order by o.inDate desc
```

The uuid column of the result is

[image: uuid2]

I already use `order by`, so why is the order of the two uuid columns different? I think there must be some principle which MySQL uses to select results from table, and what is it?

Comment: Any chance the uuids that jump share the same `inDate` values?

Comment: Guessing `indate` is just a date, not unique datetimes?  Assuming so, what sorts next is somewhat arbitrary if you don't define it.  You should probably use `order by o.indate desc, o.uuid`

Comment: without order by clause you cant guaranteed the order read this it will help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775

Answer (score 1):

The reason you would get different `uuid` values is because you have multiple rows with the same maximum value of `inDate`.

In MySQL (and SQL in general) sorts are not *stable*.  A stable sort preserves the order of the rows when key values are equal.  Why aren't sorts stable in relational databases?  Simple:  tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no known ordering.

The solution is to include an additional unique key as the last sort key.  In your case, that might be:

```
order by o.inDate desc, uuid
```

Comment: What is the algorithm the MySQL use to order the rows when key values are equal? Or, where can I find the knowledge about this?

Comment: @ZhengChenggong . . . Somehow you missed my point.  When the key values are equal, the values are indeterminate.  Whether MySQL uses a merge sort or quick sort or heap sort or something else doesn't matter.  The  ordering can be different for very similar queries.